# How to send HTML canvas as an image?

Tags: javascript, image, url, canvas, uri

I want to be able to replicate something like this: https://via.placeholder.com/150

I have some data that I'd like to put in a URL and have the response be an image. I'm using javascript to get parameters passed in the url and then build an HTML canvas. I want to be able to convert that canvas to an image and send that back as the response.

```
/**
 *    Gets URL params
*/
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,                     function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}

var fullName = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["fullName"]);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function doCanvas() {
    /* draw something */
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f7f7f7';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#4b4f54';
    ctx.font = '12px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText("Name: "+fullName, 10, 18);
}

/**
 * Draw something to canvas
 */
doCanvas();
```

The canvas works great and the data I passed in through the URL gets displayed. I still need help figuring out how to convert this canvas to an image and send that to the visitor of the URL rather than the page containing the canvas.

I appreciate any ideas on how I might accomplish this. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toDataURL` method on the canvas element to create an image from the canvas. You'll then be able to send this image to which ever backend you're working with.

Example HTML

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas">
<form action="SERVER_ROUTE_HERE" method="post" id="submit-canvas-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="canvas" id="canvas-image">
  <button>Submit Drawing</button>
</form>
```

JS

```js
let mycanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
let form = document.getElementById("submit-canvas-form");
let cvImage = document.getElementById("canvas-image");

form.onsubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let image = mycanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    cvImage.value = image;
    form.submit();
}
```